# Can't create a React component in node_modules and use it in an application

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs, react-component

I just created a new application with `create-react-app`.

I created a new project with a component and used `webpack` to transpile the JSX with `babel` and bundle everything to `/dist/bundle.js`.

I linked with `npm link` the application and the components I created in the new project.

In the application I imported the components but I'm always getting the error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Printing the components in the application they are all `undefined`.

This is the component:

**index.js**

```
import Root from './Root';

export { Root };
```

**Root.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
  }
}

export default Root;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets:['react']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-comp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

In the application

**App.js**

```
import { Root } from 'my-comp';

render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <span>Hello World</span>
      </Root>
    );
  }
```

Anyone knows what is going on? Can't I import from `bundle.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In the **webpack.config.js**, change the output object to this:

```
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2' //THIS IS IMPORTANT
}
```

It tells the engine that this is an exportable module.